# in java I want to return in one line stream to map

Tags: java, java-stream, inline

I'm trying to improve my code which already works, so here is the thing, I have a method who return a `Map`:

```java
public Map<String, String> extractPartitionsValues(java.nio.file.Path marketFile) {

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String p : this.partitions) {
        map.put(p, partitionValueFromFilePath(p, marketFile.toString()));
    }
    return map;
}
```

I want to retrun this in one line using stream and collectorsToMap but im really noob at this so I read doc and all I found but it still doesn't work, can some body help me with this.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Collectors.toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) with [`identity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html#identity()) for the key and your calculation for the value:

```
public Map<String, String> extractPartitionsValues(Path marketFile) {
    return partitions.stream()
      .collect(toMap(identity(), p -> partitionValueFromFilePath(p, marketFile.toString())));
}
```

Comment: I tend to use `p -> p` instead of `identity()` (it's shorter, doesn't require an import), but that's really personal preference.

Comment: @andy yeah it's a style thing. Either is OK, but I lean towards using the utility method because it's there for this purpose and its name describes what it does, which you don't get from a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
        Map<String, Object> collect =
                partitions.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p, p -> partitionValueFromFilePath(p, marketFile.toString())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Main point here is to get a stream from `partitions` field.

If `partitions` is defined as a string array, `Arrays.stream` should be used: `Arrays.stream(this.partitions)`.

Otherwise, if `partitions` is a collection (set or list) of strings, it has its methods `stream() / parallelStream()`.

Next, in order to use `Collectors.toMap` in its [simplest form](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-), the `partitions` field should contain only unique values.  This may be enforced by applying `.distinct()` operation to the stream if `partitions` is defined as an array or list.

So, the resulting function may look like this:

- `private String[] partitions;`:

```java
public Map<String, String> extractPartitionsValues(Path marketFile) {
    String path = marketFile.toString();
    return Arrays.stream(this.partitions)
      .distinct()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(
          p -> p, p -> partitionValueFromFilePath(p, path)
    ));
}
```

- `private List<String> partitions;`

```java
public Map<String, String> extractPartitionsValues(Path marketFile) {
    String path = marketFile.toString();
    return this.partitions.stream()
      .distinct()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(
          p -> p, p -> partitionValueFromFilePath(p, path)
    ));
}
```

- `private Set<String> partitions;`

```java
public Map<String, String> extractPartitionsValues(Path marketFile) {
    String path = marketFile.toString();
    return this.partitions.stream() // does not contain duplicates
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(
          p -> p, p -> partitionValueFromFilePath(p, path)
    ));
}
```

---

Or an overloaded [`toMap` with a merge function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) may be used to handle possible duplications of keys:

```java
private Collection<String> partitions; // could be set or list

public Map<String, String> extractPartitionsValues(Path marketFile) {
    String path = marketFile.toString();
    return this.partitions.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(
          p -> p, 
          p -> partitionValueFromFilePath(p, path), 
          (p1, p2) -> p1 // use the first key
    ));
}
```